# No such file or directory with grep command

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Following is the output of my Unix command

```
$ /data/nagios/libexec/check_http -I example.com  -C 30 -p443 --sni
OK - Certificate 'example.com' will expire on 05/10/2020 12:00.
```

But when I do a grep on the output inside a script,it shows "No such file or directory"

```
grep: OK - Certificate 'example.com' will expire on 05/10/2020 12:00.: No such file or directory
```

Below is the script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 output=`/data/nagios/libexec/check_http -I example.com  -C 30 -p443 --sni`
 grep 'OK' "$output"
```

Can anybody please guide how to resolve this. It works fine when I execute directly on commandline

```
  $ /data/nagios/libexec/check_http -I example.com  -C 30 -p443 --sni | grep OK
  OK - Certificate 'example.com' will expire on 05/10/2020 12:00.
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to grep another commands output?

Comment: You need to do `echo "$output" | grep 'OK'` or use here-strings of `bash` as  `grep 'OK' <<<"$output"`